# Strace output not showing system call

Tags: tty, strace

I am reading the source code of coreutils and I came to read `tty.c` code.
Main function of `tty` is as follows:

```
int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  char *tty;
  int optc;

  initialize_main (&argc, &argv);
  set_program_name (argv[0]);
  setlocale (LC_ALL, "");
  bindtextdomain (PACKAGE, LOCALEDIR);
  textdomain (PACKAGE);

  initialize_exit_failure (TTY_WRITE_ERROR);
  atexit (close_stdout);

  silent = false;

  while ((optc = getopt_long (argc, argv, "s", longopts, NULL)) != -1)
    {
      switch (optc)
        {
        case 's':
          silent = true;
          break;

        case_GETOPT_HELP_CHAR;

        case_GETOPT_VERSION_CHAR (PROGRAM_NAME, AUTHORS);

        default:
          usage (TTY_FAILURE);
        }
    }

  if (optind < argc)
    error (0, 0, _("extra operand %s"), quote (argv[optind]));

  tty = ttyname (STDIN_FILENO); 
  if (!silent)
    {
      if (tty)
        puts (tty);
      else
        puts (_("not a tty"));
    }

  exit (isatty (STDIN_FILENO) ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

To my understanding the line which gets the current tty is `tty = ttyname (STDIN_FILENO);` 
But when I run `tty` using `strace` in the output of `strace` there is no call to `ttyname`. 
What is the reason?

Here is the output of strace:

```
> strace -c tty
/dev/pts/3
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           read
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           write
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           open
  0.00    0.000000           0         5           close
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           stat
  0.00    0.000000           0         5           fstat
  0.00    0.000000           0        10           mmap
  0.00    0.000000           0         4           mprotect
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           munmap
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           brk
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           ioctl
  0.00    0.000000           0         1         1 access
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           execve
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           readlink
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           arch_prctl
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000000                    41         1 total
```

No `ttyname` is the list!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that [`ttyname(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ttyname.3.html) isn't a [system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), it's a C library function. You can check out its implementation, *e.g.* [in `glibc`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/ttyname.c;h=7a001b444550af39dbdcc097a06e6f303d657bdf;hb=HEAD), to see what system calls it uses itself (and which you'll then see in `strace`'s output).

To trace library calls on Linux, you can use [ltrace](http://www.ltrace.org/) (which can also trace system calls). (Thanks to [Marki555](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/13946/marki555) for the suggestion.)

Comment: Thanks. Is this a list of all system calls? http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html

Comment: @coffeMug yes, for Linux anyway!

Comment: is there a way to trace function calls of a binary similar to the way `strace` works (apart from `gdb`)?

Comment: @coffeMug try `ltrace`, which shows library calls

Comment: @Marki555 thanks. Good thing about `ltrace` is that it can also trace system calls.